# how to connect moodle with keycloak

Tags: keycloak, moodle

I want to connect moodle with keycloak, so the user may login moodle with their keycloak acoount. I cannot find the tutorial on the internet. Has anyone managed to connect keycloak to moodle?

Comment: Use oauth2 - https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/OAuth_2_authentication